# Spark Structured Streaming + pyspark app returns "Initial job has not accepted any resources"

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-kafka, cassandra, spark-cassandra-connector

## RunCode

```
spark-submit --master spark://{SparkMasterIP}:7077
--deploy-mode cluster --packages org.apache.spark:spark-sql-kafka-0-10_2.12:3.1.2,
com.datastax.spark:spark-cassandra-connector_2.12:3.2.0,
com.github.jnr:jnr-posix:3.1.15
--conf spark.dynamicAllocation.enabled=false
--conf com.datastax.spark:spark.cassandra.connectiohost={SparkMasterIP==CassandraIP},
spark.sql.extensions=com.datastax.spark.connector.CassandraSparkExtensions test.py
```

## Source Code

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark.sql.functions import *
from pyspark.sql.types import *
from pyspark.sql import SQLContext

# Spark Bridge local to spark_master == Connect master
spark = SparkSession.builder \
    .master("spark://{SparkMasterIP}:7077") \
    .appName("Spark_Streaming+kafka+cassandra") \
    .config('spark.cassandra.connection.host', '{SparkMasterIP==CassandraIP}') \
    .config('spark.cassandra.connection.port', '9042') \
    .getOrCreate()

# Parse Schema of json
schema = StructType() \
        .add("col1", StringType()) \
        .add("col2", StringType()) \
        .add("col3", StringType()) \
        .add("col4", StringType()) \
        .add("col5", StringType()) \
        .add("col6", StringType()) \
        .add("col7", StringType())

# Read Stream From {TOPIC} at BootStrap
df = spark.readStream \
  .format("kafka") \
  .option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", "{KAFKAIP}:9092") \
  .option('startingOffsets','earliest') \
  .option("subscribe", "{TOPIC}") \
  .load() \
  .select(from_json(col("value").cast("String"), schema).alias("parsed_value")) \
  .select("parsed_value.*")

df.printSchema()

# write Stream at cassandra
ds = df.writeStream \
  .trigger(processingTime='15 seconds') \
  .format("org.apache.spark.sql.cassandra") \
  .option("checkpointLocation","./checkPoint") \
  .options(table='{TABLE}',keyspace="{KEY}") \
  .outputMode('append') \
  .start()

ds.awaitTermination()
```

Error Code

```
Initial job has not accepted any resources; check your cluster UI to ensure that workers are registered and have sufficient resources
```

I was checked Spark UI, workers have no problem.

here is my Spark status
[image]
[![enter image description here][2]][2]

my plan is
kafka(DBIP)--readStream-->LOCAL(DriverIP)--writeStream-->Spark&kafka&casaandra(MasterIP)

DBIP, DriverIP, MasterIP is different IP.
LOCAL have no spark, so i use pyspark on python_virtualenv

## Edit

[image]

Comment: Try adding  `--conf spark.cores.max=6 --num-executors 3 --executor-cores 2 --executor-memory 3g`  to your `spark-submit`

Comment: @VikramsinhShinde i tried yet and now but same error

Comment: Could you share spark ui after submitting your application with parameteres @VikramsinhShinde has suggested?

Comment: @ozlemg sorry i didn`t know your comment, I Edited

Comment: Can you check actual free memory of your workers?

Comment: @ozlemg thanks your comment i already solved :)

Answer (score 0):

You app can't run because there are no resources available in your Spark cluster.

If you look closely at the Spark UI screenshot you posted, all the cores are used on all the 3 workers. That means there are no cores left for any other apps so any new submitted app will have to wait until resources are available before it can be scheduled. Cheers!

---

Please support the Apache Cassandra community by hovering over the `cassandra` tag above and click on **Watch tag**.  Thanks!

Comment: image :
running applications is source code and cores use on source code but spawn error code